# How to know whether SQL is successfully executed when programming using Pro*C?

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-pro-c

I recently programme using Pro*C to access Oracle database like this:

```
cmd[128];
dpc_set_sqlca(&sqlca);
strcpy(cmd,"EXECUTE IMMEDIATE");
dpc_exec_immediate(sql_string);
SQLCODE = sqlca.sqlcode;
```

How to know whether the SQL has successfully executed?

For example, how to know whether a table exists in oracle DB?
How to know whether an `INSERT` statement is successfully executed?

Comment: Other than looking as `SQLSTATE` or `SQLCODE`, or `sqlca.sqlcode`, as explained in [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e10825/pc_09err.htm)? (Setting `SQLCODE` manually like that probably isn't a good idea, but if both are declared they should both have the same value anyway). That also mentions using `sqlca.sqlerrd[2]` to get the number of rows processed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all in Pro*C, SQL statements can be executed directly, by using the `EXEC SQL` directive, like

`EXEC SQL INSERT INTO.... VALUES...`

All other SQL statements can be executed in the same way. Every Pro*C uses `SQLCA.H` header file like `EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA.H`; This line tells the Pro*C precompiler that the program has SQL statements that will need to be interpreted in it.

Dynamic sql can also be executed in Pro*C, like

```
char *cmd = "INSERT INTO emp VALUES(1234, 'jon', 3)";
EXEC SQL PREPARE q FROM :cmd;
EXEC SQL EXECUTE q;
```

Or

```
char cmd[255] = "TRUNCATE TABLE tab_name";
EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :cmd;
```

**Note the `:` symbol, this denotes that the variable is a bind variable to the SQL engine.

Now coming to Exception handling. Below are some of the examples that you could use to handle SQL errors in a Pro*C-

```
  EXEC SQL INSERT INTO .... VALUES...;
  if SQL_ERROR_FOUND  //Exception Handling starts
  {
       sprintf(err_data,"INSERT/SELECT");                  
       //write error to log file, use SQLCODE to see what particular error happened
       return(-1);
  }
```

Cursor Open-

```
 EXEC SQL OPEN c_cursor;
 if SQL_ERROR_FOUND   //Exception Handling starts
 {
    sprintf(err_data,"CURSOR FETCH: cursor=c_item");
    //write error to log file
    return(-1);
 }
 else if NO_DATA_FOUND
 {//do something
 }
```

Or with dynamic SQL-

```
 EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :cmd;
  if SQL_ERROR_FOUND
  {
        sprintf(err_data,"EXECUTE DYNAMIC STATEMENT %s", cmd); 
        //write error to log file 
        return(FATAL);
  }
```

And so on... Remember, the exception/error handling `if..else` should be just below the `EXEC SQL <statement>` for which you would like to handle the errors.

`SQLCODE (sqlca.sqlcode)` is the most commonly used error code. Declared as a long at the
top of the program, preferably just after the inclusion of `SQLCA.H` as `long SQLCODE;`.
SQLCODE is populated by Oracle after every SQL statement and holds the Oracle server error number. This code can be used for error handling and logging purposes too.

Comment: Is `if SQL_ERROR_FOUND` valid code or just pseudo-code? is `SQL_ERROR_FOUND` some custom macro?

Comment: It is defined as `#define SQL_ERROR_FOUND (SQLCODE != 0 && SQLCODE != 1403)`